# Array being replaced rather than added

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I'm trying to store in another array but everytime I give the initial array values through a form, it replaces the previous array in the array. What could be causing this?

```
$bar = array(
    'model' => $_SESSION['model'],
    'qty'   => $_SESSION['qty'],
    'id'    => $_SESSION['id'],
);

$foo = Array(
    'key' => $bar,
);
```

The values are beign grabbed by a form like

```
$_SESSION['model'] = $_GET['model'];
```

Comment: All you've given us is the array contents.  Show us the code where you manipulate them.

Comment: @Daedalus all I'm doing at the moment is a var_dump($foo) so I can see if it's being added or not and it's not, it;s replacing the last one in there.

Comment: So, let me clarify; you set a new value for session's 'model' key, and you instead want to add to it, instead of it getting replaced?

Comment: That's correct @Daedalus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your comments sure explain things, so let me start off by saying that in this line:

```
$_SESSION['model'] = $_GET['model'];
```

You are setting a new value for the key 'model'; that is what `=` does.

If you want to add to it, it should simply be a matter of..

```
$_SESSION['model'][] = $_GET['model'];
```

This will add a new array item to the array 'model', assuming model is initially an array.

Comment: Don't worry, was definitely going to.